# Wright Omega Function, Ceiling

Tags: calculus, functions, lambert-w, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In the Wright Omega function, the following is used as the **subscript for the Lambert W function**:

$$\left\lceil\frac{\Im(z)-\pi}{2\pi}\right\rceil$$

Here is the full function for context (from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Omega_function)):

$$\omega(z)=W_{\left\lceil\frac{\Im(z)-\pi}{2\pi}\right\rceil}e^z$$

I understand that $W_0$ is the real branch of the Lambert W function, and that $W_{-1}$ is the imaginary branch. But in this case, the subscript can end up being numbers other than $0$ and $-1$.

So what does this subscript mean in this case?

Comment: I recently learned that $\Im(z)$ returns the imaginary part of the number (ie, $\Im(2i+3)=2$). I'll update my question. (whoa, got the Tumbleweed badge for this question)

Comment: I would not call $W_{-1}$ an "imaginary branch", simply because it does take real values in the interval $[-1/e,0)$.

Comment: @J.M. Aside from calling it "the $W_{-1}$ branch", what would the correct terminology be? The $W_0$ branch is called the principal branch. I have seen the $W_{-1}$ branch called "the lower branch" and "the non-principal branch" but I don't know what the correct terminology is.

Comment: Since the functions are relatively new, I don't think I've seen terminology settle. Usually, I refer to non-principal branches by their index: "the $-1$-branch", but I've also become fond of "lower branch". Whatever terminology you settle with, be sure that you indicate what they mean at the beginning of whatever you're going to write about them: "...where $W_{-1}(z)$ is the 'lower branch' of the Lambert function..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the ["unwinding number"](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/editors.pdf),

$$\mathcal K(z)=\left\lceil\frac{\Im z-\pi}{2\pi}\right\rceil$$

which satisfies the relation

$$\log\exp z=z+2\pi i\mathcal K(z)$$

and is indeed an integer. If you read the linked paper, you'll notice that the definition there is a little different, but Corless and Jeffrey explained in [their paper on Wright $\omega$](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/wrightomega.pdf) why they modified the definition.

This fits in perfectly fine with the Lambert function, which does expect integer subscripts in the usual case; however, if you read their paper further, you'll find that the Wright function then allows the extension of the Lambert function $W_k(z)$ to arbitrary $k$!

Anyway, read the two papers I linked to if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks! Both of those papers are very insightful, I can't believe I haven't stumbled onto them before!